# C# WinForms - DrawImage without losing animation

Tags: c#, graphics

How to `DrawImage` without losing animation?

```
        pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(20, 20);
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(pictureBox1.Image);
        Image i = Properties.Resources.SuperMario; //Animated GIF; sprite; 20px X 20px
        g.DrawImage(i, 
            new Rectangle(0, 0, 20, 20),
            new Rectangle(0, 0, 20, 20),
            GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
        pictureBox1.Refresh();
```

The above codes, copies image portion from an animated sprite sheet (GIF format) to `PictureBox`' `Image`. Unfortunately, the animation is lost.

This is the sprite sheet: http://www.google.com/imgres?q=sprite+20x20&um=1&hl=en&client=firefox-a&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&biw=1067&bih=671&tbm=isch&tbnid=ulN4JRy6N4ToSM:&imgrefurl=http://nkelsch.deviantart.com/art/Super-Mario-20x20-Sprites-83482505&docid=GOCF1PgjPytbPM&imgurl=http://www.deviantart.com/download/83482505/Super_Mario_20x20_Sprites_by_nkelsch.gif&w=251&h=356&ei=4orQTvXPIKePiAerio24Dg&zoom=1&iact=hc&vpx=89&vpy=154&dur=7579&hovh=267&hovw=188&tx=131&ty=137&sig=107474527571502851152&page=1&tbnh=122&tbnw=86&start=0&ndsp=18&ved=1t:429,r:0,s:0

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load the entire gif in picture box and position it such that only relevant portion is shown in picture box. Thats how sprites work. You don't have to copy the portion of a particular frame because yes that would obviously lose animation.

Put your picture box inside a panel and then set the location of picture box to the position of sprite element.

Comment: That's what I was thinking, but I cannot find any tutorial on how to do that. Is that even possible?

Comment: That's... a really clever hack actually.  Be aware that there may be severe performance issues with it though.

Comment: I'll go to this solution. Performance wise, I still don't know, but I guess, copying image has lot more processing than moving the `Image` inside a `Panel`.

Comment: +1 Thanks for time and effort. Everyone's idea really helped me.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to use some sort of timer / thread to continually update the image at the correct animation rate.  graphics.drawImage only draws the image once at the time it is called, it doesn't understand animation.

If you really want to use this method of animation you should keep a variable around to hold the frame index.  Drop a `Timer` component on the form and set it to fire at the interval your animation is animated at.  When the timer fires increment your frame counter, then clear, and redraw the picturebox using the bounds of the frame with the new index.  You should wrap your frame counter back to 0 when it goes beyond the max frame in your animation.

Comment: Using `Graphics.Animate`? I don't fully understand, when I set `Properties.Resources.SuperMario` as the `Image` of `PictureBox`, it gives me animation. I just lost the animation when I try to create image out of the source image.

Comment: if your resource is animated just set the picturebox's image to the resource image you pulled out.  But it sounds to me like you are using a sprite sheet instead of an animated gif.

Comment: Yep, I mentioned that, I'm using a sprite sheet :)

Comment: I see now.  I have never actually seen an Animated Sprite Sheet before.  You wouldn't be able to directly using graphics.drawimage to paint the sprite because because it doesn't support animation.  You may be better off splitting this animated gif in to separate sprite sheets, one for each frame.  Change my example so that the frameindex actually tells you which sheet to draw from, instead of changing the source location.

Comment: I'm not sure that I fully understand your ultimate goal here, but if you are trying to create a game there are a few flaws with this method.  If you want to do this "correctly" you really need to look in to timers, threads, or some other type of game loop where you can redraw your scene as needed.

Comment: I have a link in my question, I use that Super Mario sprite sheet. Hm, Hasan Khan's idea is interesting, is there any way to achieve that? Say, I'll set the `PictureBox.Image` to the sprite sheet, then I'll just set the offset, that's a lot easier if possible.

Comment: Ohh, as a side note. make sure you call `.dispose` on your `graphics` objects when you are done with them.  Otherwise they build up in memory until the garbage collector can free them.

Comment: +1 Thanks for time and effort. Everyone's idea really helped me.

Answer (score 1):

`PictureBox` understands animated GIFs inherently.

Why do you need to draw it manually in you Update method?

It should be enough to make a `PictureBox`, set the animated GIF as the `Image` of the `PictureBox`.

Also make sure that you do not run any blocking code on the GUI thread, as that will keep the animation from running.

Comment: As I have said, the source image is a sprite sheet, based on user input, I need to change the image of the `PictureBox`.

Comment: I missed the part that the source image was a sprite sheet. I would rethink the part of your game where you decided to go the "Animated gif sprite map" path, and instead make a proper sprite sheet with each animation frame as a separate sprite on the sprite sheet, and using a loop to manually display the animation properly. Animated gifs do not give you enough flexibility in this case, and using DrawImage to draw part of the image copies only the pixels, not the actual animated gif part of your image, so I cant see any way to retain animation in this case.

Comment: His sprite sheet isn't the traditional type of sprite sheet.  It's actually already an animated gif with different characters in each slot, instead of different frames of the same character in each slot.  It's going to be tricky to get this to work from this source image.

Comment: Bradley - Yes, I understood that as well. To get it to work as he wants, he actually need to have a graphics.DrawImage overload where he can select the correct frame in the animated gif, and there simply is nothing similar to that in the GDI+ API to help him. So I think he will have to rethink, and make a traditional sprite sheet. It will save him a lot of grief in the long run imo.

Comment: GDI+ does actually support animated gifs via the Image.SetActiveFrame method.  But still, as you pointed out, DrawImage isn't going to animate it by it's self.

Comment: +1 Thanks for time and effort. Everyone's idea really helped me.

Comment: Bradley - Then I learned something in this question also then ;) Didn't know about that one. Probably I will never have the need for it though ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can visit the link to get source code http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/NGif.aspx

Comment: The source image (which is sprite sheet) is already animated, is just that the animation is lost whenever I copy it.

Comment: @domanokz:   Image i = Properties.Resources.SuperMario can get only the 1st frame

Comment: +1 Thanks for time and effort. Everyone's idea really helped me.

Comment: You can decode the any gif resource into frames array and then you can select what frame you want to copy. I have used this way in my game (it is to compilcated to post here)

Comment: If you want to make your own game, you should redraw the form using double buffer [link]http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/DoubleBuffering.aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
    class WinForm : Form
    {
        bool FrameLoop = false;
        int FrameIndex = 0;
        int FrameCount = 0;
        FrameDimension FrameDimension = null;
        List<int> DelayTime = new List<int>();
        Image img;

        protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnLoad(e);
            this.DoubleBuffered = true;
            img = Image.FromFile("C:\\debug.gif");
            if (img.FrameDimensionsList != null)
                foreach (Guid i in img.FrameDimensionsList)
                {
                    FrameDimension = new FrameDimension(i);
                    FrameCount = img.GetFrameCount(FrameDimension);
                }
            if (FrameCount > 1)
            {
                foreach (PropertyItem i in img.PropertyItems)
                {
                    if (i.Id == 0x5100)
                    {
                        for (int j = 0; j < FrameCount; j++)
                        {
                            DelayTime.Add(BitConverter.ToInt32(i.Value, j * 4));
                        }
                    }
                    else if (i.Id == 0x5101)
                    {
                        FrameLoop = true;
                    }
                }
                this.BeginInvoke(new EventHandler(Animation));
            }
        }

        private void Animation(object sender,EventArgs e)
        {
            img.SelectActiveFrame(FrameDimension, FrameIndex);
            this.Refresh();
            Application.DoEvents();
            Thread.Sleep(DelayTime[FrameIndex] * 10);

            FrameIndex++;
            if (FrameIndex >= FrameCount)
            {
                if (FrameLoop)
                    FrameIndex = 0;
                else
                    return;
            }
            Animation(sender, e);
        }

        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            if (img == null)
                return;
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(img, new Point(0, 0));
            //base.OnPaint(e);
        }
    }
```